# How do I move the contents of my master branch to a new Git branch?

Tags: git

I've been making some vast changes on the master branch of my Git repository. I'm pretty new to Git and so I'm wondering:

How can I move my current master branch to a new branch and recreate my master branch from scratch for a particular folder of files?

As an example, I have another folder, like `new_stuff`, that contains the new files to be added to the master branch, and that old master is a new branch named `old_master`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Within the directory of the repository, in the command line type the following:

```
git branch -m master old_master
git branch master
```

This should be enough :)

Comment: this does not work :/ The first command produces git help listing

Comment: @SpyrosP: You are right, I obviously used a syntax for changing name of a remote, not a branch. Corrected now.

Comment: What will happen on push in this case? Will git understand, that it needs to rename master in the remote repo also?

Comment: I might add this there: git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master

Otherwise the new local master will not track remote master.

Answer (score 6):

Use `git branch -m master old_master` to rename master to something else. Then do something like `git checkout -b master HEAD~2` to create the new master as per your needs ( in this case till the 2nd commit from previous HEAD ) Now add / replace the folder `new_stuff` and commit in `master`